# Were "African levies" paid during the Hut Tax War of 1898?

Tags: 19th-century, africa, newspapers, west-africa

The [Hut Tax War of 1898](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hut_Tax_War_of_1898) was fought largely between the [British](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Leone_Colony_and_Protectorate), supported by freed African, African-American, and Afro-Caribbean slaves, [called the Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Leone_Creole_people) trying to colonize [Sierra Leone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Sierra_Leone), and the indigenous people, the [Mende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mende_people). The British governor imposed a tax on each hut, according to size, including unoccupied huts. The Mende were upset and rebelled. The rebellion lasted 9 months. See the above links for more information.

The part I am interested in on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hut_Tax_War_of_1898) is where it lists the casualties. It says:

> *Apart from support units and a 280-man strong naval brigade, British colonial forces consisted of detachments from the West India Regiments, the newly-formed West Africa Regiment, the Sierra Leone Frontier Police and local African levies.[8] These forces combined suffered 67 killed and 184 wounded during the rebellion, in addition to the deaths of 90 African porters and an unknown number of casualties among the levies (which were not recorded).*

This is the only time "levies" are mentioned. I checked the Oxford Dictionary to see if "levies" was used in some manner I hadn't come across before, but no all of the definitions were meaning something along the lines of "to raise", usually a tax or something like that. So, in relation to humans, I would assume that levies are soldiers raised by the indigenous peoples of the area as a sort of tribute to the British Government. This led me to wonder, were these conscripts or volunteers and how were they compensated, if at all?

The only other mention I found of these "levies" treats them similarly dismissively. The [London Gazette](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/27149/page/8653), cited in the Wikipedia article, says:

> *The friendly levies at times lost considerably, but, save in the few cases I have mentioned, I have no record of their casualties.*

Wikipedia does mention a book *British Battles and Medals*, which I just bought used for a painful $35, but I am unsure what it says, if anything, about the levies. The shipping time is 7-21 days. Otherwise, I find no mention of the "levies". Now, I did find evidence of indigenous groups fighting on behalf of the British, such as in the above Gazette article, but it never says anything about how they were raised, i.e. via the barrel of a rifle, cash or land, or something else. Any information someone could find on the particulars of the African troops in the 9-month war would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Page 150 of [this](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/14196/1/464710_Vol1.pdf) document tells us that levies in Cape Town were paid, but it's possible that rates differed by nation.

Comment: @CDR I imagine they were most likely paid in Sierra Leone as well, then. Thanks. I still hope someone could write an answer that specifically answers for this incident.